# Dockable Append window

Tags: interface, append

Is there is a way to set a File browser UI pane to append mode or something of the like for a quick drag and drop Kit-bashing type of workflow? Even an addon would be nice.

I did see the paid Asset manager addon however for what I'm looking fo $40 is steep.